# How to install LinqToObjectiveC cocoapod?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I use pod 'LinqToObjectiveC' to install this specific cocoapod but i get back [!] Unknown command: `LinqToObjectiveC`
Did you mean: deintegrate?

There are no specific instructions at https://cocoapods.org/pods/LinqToObjectiveC
I do not know if i can install it using the pod command or not.
Any help to install it via pod command?

Comment: Do you have `podfile` at all? `pod 'LinqToObjectiveC'` is not a command, it's a line to add in your podfile. If you don't have a Podfile, check before on `CocoaPods` how to start (pod init, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the following lines to your `Podfile`:
`pod 'LinqToObjectiveC', '~> 2.1'`

more info: https://cocoapods.org/pods/LinqToObjectiveC